# Redirecting to new Django url after successful Ajax function execution?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

I have one `ajax` function, which is doing request to check whether user input username is valid or not.  For that i wrote one `ajax` function and created one view to check the validity. The view check the validity and return a `JSON` response.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'some/url',
      data : {'username' : 'username'},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.results == "failed"){alert('Username not available')}
        else if (data.results == 'success' {location.href = "some/new/url" + with json_data}
     },
     complete : function(){

}
   })
```

};

If the username is taken, it ask the user to input again and if it's available, a new page will be loaded, and the `datatype` from the server will be a `JSON data` with multiple values. How can i load the new page with `JSON data` as a parameter. I used `location.href` but how can i put `json` as a parameter?

EDIT:
My views.py code

```
def validate_username(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username', None)
    isAvailable = 'Checking_in_database'
    data ={} #JSON Data
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: can you post your django view code as well ? Also try location.href in success function rather than in complete.

Comment: @Aniket, updated.

Comment: You can't pass json_data to new url from js. Instead create some url `/data/<id_of_the_user>` and get the user context and pass from server.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why don't you work with it in SERVER side???

It is better if you check the conditions in Server.

But for the case using location.href = "some/new/url" you can put dictionary for it like:

```
location.href = "some/new/url" {data:data}
```